# Why was this question deleted by Community?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

As far as I can tell [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91192/10762) wasn't a migration, it wasn't problematic, and it isn't an autodelete based on negative feedback (it even had an accepted answer). Why was it deleted by Community?

Did the user delete their account? There appears to be no account associated with that username, but as far as I know, after you post you can only get your account deleted by contacting support, which seems to have happened extremely quickly (since the question was posted less than an hour ago), so I suspect it's not that.

Comment: Embarrassment would be a plausible enough scenario...

Comment: @jasonwryan Why would they accept an answer if they intended to immediately delete it? As far as I know, you can't delete your own questions directly when you have answers.

Comment: It was semi-humorous; *I* was embarrassed by the question...

Comment: @terdon - I was just looking at it as well, it doesn't appear to be one from troll. I would assume that the OP deleted themselves as jasonwryan has indicated. Not sure how to confirm that though. The title was: "How to ensure file is saved even if pc is turned off via power cord being un-plugged?"

Comment: @slm I remember that one, I think it _was_ the troll.

Comment: @terdon - yeah I wasn't on a lot yesterday but I don't even remember seeing that Q, so it was dealt with quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Given the user account doesn't show up in the system any longer I would assume that this account was linked to a spam/troller and was deleted.

I would be doubly cautious when answering Q's from new users at least for while, we've had a rash of seemingly valid questions posted that have turned out to be from a troll. I hate to have to do this myself but it saves on the annoyance of giving a good answer only to have it disappear when his account is later deleted.

If you feel this was a good Q + A I would suggest "rescuing" it by posting yourself and answering it. I've done this [on one other occasion to save](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90657/how-to-remove-a-usb-drive-without-worrying-if-its-been-unmounted) what I thought was a good answer to keep on the site that Gilles posted.